# notepad++ regex to replace multiple values with different replacement

Tags: regex, encoding, replace, notepad++

I have lots of text that have url encoding that needs to be fixed.

As it's rather tedious to keep doing find/replace for every one,

Does anyone have a regex to replace multiple characters at a time?

Example:

Replace...

- `%20` with a space
- `%5B` with `[`
- `%5D` with `]`
- `%28` with `(`
- `%29` with `)`

Comment: do you mean to use "and %5d to" as replacement or just %5D   ?

Comment: I edited my post a bit

I want to replace the url encoding with symbols.

Comment: I have updated the answer a bit as per your update... have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find by the following regex:

```
(%20)|(%5B)|(%5D)|(%28)|(%29)
```

and replace by this:

```
(?1 )(?2\[)(?3\[)(?4\()(?5\))
```

Explanation:

```
(?1replacementA)(?2replacmentB)(?3replacmentC)....
```

1. where ?1 indicates to replace first capture group value %20 by
   '    replacementA'
2. where ?2 indicates to replace second capture group %5B by
       'replacementB'
3. where ?3 indicates to replace third capture group %28 by
       'replacementC'

It is possible since notepad++ 6

Comment: i tried  
  
Find:          
(%20)|(%5B)|(%5D)|(%28)|(%29)     

Replace with:  
(? )(?[)(?]) (?() (?))  
  
But it didn't work.

Comment: @Tyler watch out the update in the answer you need to escape your brackets as they special characters for regex and also you need the number too in your regex as that indicaters which group you want to replace

Comment: okay i've got it to this now: (?1 )(?2\[)(?3\]) (?4() (?5))

how do i get the parenthesis ones to work?